# need to use std_logic_Arith with std_logic_signed/unsigned

Tags: vhdl

I read in many VHDL file headers :   use  ieee.std_logic_arith.all along with ieee.std_logic_signed.all , i can't see any benefit of this as the latter package(Signed)makes use of the former(Arith) automatically in its implementation. Any clarification why they are used together?

I have the same remark re. ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all
Thank you

Comment: Along with @fru1tbat's advice you can get the same behavior as non-standard `std_logic_[un]signed` in VHDL-2008 by using `ieee.numeric_std_[un]signed`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you use a package, you are not automatically importing all of the packages that package uses, so you need to use both explicitly if you want the features of both.

`std_logic_signed`/`unsigned` overloads mathematical and relational operators to treat `std_logic_vector` as a signed/unsigned number, respectively. `std_logic_arith` overloads the same operators, but only specifically for the `signed` and `unsigned` types it defines. If you want to use specific numeric types, you use `std_logic_arith`. If you want to treat all generic `std_logic_vector`s as signed or unsigned numbers, you use one of the others.

Or actually, don't use either, and use the standard `ieee.numeric_std` instead, which accomplishes the same thing as the `std_logic_arith` (you will need to typecast instead of directly operating on `std_logic_vector`, but this is generally better anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. you said: If you want to use specific numeric types, you use std_logic_arith; could you please give an example of other numeric types that are defined in std_logic_arith other than signed and unsigned data types

Comment: I did not mean to imply that there are other types. I was distinguishing explicit numeric types from function overloads that treat generic `std_logic_vector`s implicitly as numeric types.